# How to create an android autostart application?

Tags: android, delphi, delphi-xe5

How to create an android **autostart application**? my app shows special date notifications and it must automatically start. tnx

Comment: Take a look at services

Comment: You can find your answer here: http://dannywind.nl/auto-start-delphi-xe5-android-app-after-boot/

Comment: Means you want your app will start after a particular data and time ?

Comment: I want app start after boot.

Comment: Tnx. My app started automatically. Now I want hide app in boot start. (only show form in manually run)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) to schedule a time for when you'd like your application to launch. And you can use [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) to launch your app on a specific operating system event such as boot complete.

Comment: I work in XE5 and can't find "AlarmManager" and "BroadcastReceiver"

Comment: Please see the tutorial as suggested by Filipe.Fonseca in a comment above. It has references to using BroadcastReceiver in an XE5 environment.