# How to run app when android boots , without its form being visible on-screen?

Tags: android, delphi, delphi-xe5

I asked question in : "[How to create an android autostart application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22014178/how-to-create-an-android-autostart-application)" and my app start automatically. Now I want my app to run when Android boots, but **without its form being visible on-screen** (only show form in manually run)

Answer (score 1):

```
        <receiver android:name="com.example.RebootReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

In the RebootReceiver you can start service instead of activity, and do your logic in service.